# Android - Binding library to an application

Tags: android

First of all, I am a newbie on Android. I will be distributing a library file that I've recently built. I am not developing an app, I am only developing/distributing this library. The app development will be done by the customer. What I want is to activate this library only for the apps that the customer and I agreed upon, so that no unauthorized apps can use this library. Is there any way to do this?

If not, can you please suggest some alternative ways?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Include your library in your app. That's all. No other app will access it.

Comment: Yes, no need to distribute it.

Comment: Maybe it is unclear, I've edited the question too. I am not developing an app, I just want to distribute this library. The app development will be done by the customer. What I want is to activate this library only for the apps that the customer and I agreed upon, so that no unauthorized apps can use this library.

Comment: @FrankN.Stein, I've updated the question. Can you please take a look once more? Thanks!